# How to get the data from selected row in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview

I have created tree view in tkinter and the column code is here

```
        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(self.treeviewFrame)
        self.treeview['columns'] = ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')

        self.treeview.column('#0',width=50,minwidth=25)
        self.treeview.column('1',width=50,minwidth=25,anchor=W)
        self.treeview.column('2',width=50,minwidth=25,anchor=W)
        self.treeview.column('3',width=50,minwidth=25,anchor=W)
        self.treeview.column('4',width=50,minwidth=25,anchor=W)
        self.treeview.column('5',width=50,minwidth=25,anchor=W)
        self.treeview.column('6',width=50,minwidth=25,anchor=W)
        self.treeview.column('7',width=50,minwidth=25,anchor=W)


        self.treeview.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self.selectedRow)

        self.treeview.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        self.treeViewData()
```

For retrieving the selected row I used the below code

```
self.treeview.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self.selectedRow)

def selectedRow(self,a):
        self.curItem = self.treeview.focus()
        self.contents = self.treeview.item(self.curItem)
        print(self.contents['values'])
```

while printing the contents[values] the first row `#0` which I named as S.No is not printed. Is there any way of retrieving those values from `#0`

There are eight columns but only 7 values are printed. The first row is not printed. Please help me!

Comment: Can you also include a bit more code? Maybe like an example, so we can run it

Comment: @CoolCloud Added!

Comment: Column #0 is the one by default and normally filled by the option text. So I guess #0 is not a value.

Comment: try adding `print(self.contents['text'])` before this line `print(self.contents['values'])` and say if it appears.

Comment: @Atlas435 Yeah It worked! Thank you! You helped me a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column #0 is the one by default and normally filled by the option text. So I guess #0 is not a value.

try adding `print(self.contents['text'])` before this line `print(self.contents['values'])` and see.